# Nullpointer Exception for @Autowired annotation while using that in spring security dofilter method of authentication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have Service class annotated with `@Service` as shown below:

```java
@Service
public class SimpleApplicationSettingManager implements ApplicationSettingManager {
  
    @Autowired
    ApplicationSettingsDao applicationSettingsDao;

    //Method to Fetch value from the database
    @Override
    public boolean isConfigValue() {
         return applicationSettingsDao.getSettingsByKey(Constants.CONFIG_VALUE)
                .getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("true")?true:false;
    }
}
```

DAO class

```
public interface ApplicationSettingsDao extends GenericDao<ApplicationSettings, Long> {

    /**
     * @param key of the setting to retrive value
     * @return the value mapped against the key.
     */
    @Transactional
    ApplicationSettings getSettingsByKey(String key);
}
```

Below I am trying to Autowire in the Spring Security to keep into the session

```java
public class AuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
   
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationSettingManager applicationSettingManager;

    public AuthenticationProcessingFilter(String filterProcessesUrl){
      super(filterProcessesUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

      if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession();
        isCIAMEnabled= **applicationSettingManager**.isConfigValue();
        httpSession.setAttribute(Constants.SESSION_ATTR_CIAM_ENABLED, isCIAMEnabled);
      }
      super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }
}
```

It results in a `NullPointerException` as shown below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at service.SimpleApplicationSettingManager.isConfigValue(SimpleApplicationSettingManager.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.isConfigValue(Unknown Source)
at web.filter.security.ciam.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:85)
```

Comment: The exception says that the NPE is in SimpleApplicationSettingManager.isEnabledConfigValue, but that method doesn't appear in the code you've shown.

Comment: That says `public boolean isConfigValue()` not `isEnabledConfigValue`.

Comment: Having the code for `ApplicationSettingsDao` or at least knowing the return type of the method `getSettingsByKey` would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there are 2 possible reasons for this:

1. `getSettingsByKey(Constants.CONFIG_VALUE)` returns `null`;
2. `getSettingsByKey(Constants.CONFIG_VALUE)` in fact returns a valid not null `ApplicationSettings` but then `getValue()` method called on it returns `null`.